# Legendre wavelets for solving Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, wavelets

Can Legendre (or Haar) wavelets be used for Solving Linear Systems of Differential Equations with **variable coefficients**?

If the answer is yes, could you suggest some good references (book, article etc.) ?

Comment: Do you mean using them to represent an approximate (numerical) solutions or exact solutions? Also, you clarified "systems of differential equations with variable coefficients", but did you also mean "linear DE" (it seems so, because you are talking about coefficients)?

Comment: I want to find numerical solutions for Linear Systems of Differential Equations with variable coefficients by Wavelets.

Comment: Ok, then you should edit the post to add "linear" to the description. Maybe you could also clarify why do you specifically need Wavelets as opposed to all the other numerical methods. Maybe add the problem (or a class of problems) you are planning to solve